# Clearing out typed text from a vuetify v-autocomplete after drop down item is selected

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, v-autocomplete

I have this v-autocomplete field that has a list of items in a drop down. It's a multiselect, so many items can be selected.

```
<v-autocomplete 
  v-model="defendantCode"
  label="Defendant Code"
  :items="defendantCodeOptions"                          
  :loading="defendantCodeIsLoading"
  :filter="customFilter"
  :clear-on-select="true"
  clearable
  multiple
  dense>
</v-autocomplete>
```

But the problem I'm having is that when the user starts to type something into the field to filter the list, then selects an item in the list, the users typed text stays in the field, it doesn't get cleared or overwritten by the selected list item.

Is there a way to remove this when the list item is selected?

ex.

1. user has drop down list to select items from

[image]

2. user starts to type in a item to filter

[image]

3. then user selects item, but the initial text remains in the field

[image]

Comment: Multiselect in an autocomplete actually means you don't want the input reset when an item has been checked. Call it what you want, but the behavior of "multi-selecting" you're after is achievable by ***not*** using multiselect at all and adding each selected item to some collection and allowing for the default reset of autocomplete after each selection. If you need more help, consider adding a [mcve].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hmm this was an interesting one, but going to the actual component code revealed a "searchInput" prop which is what you're after.

So you want your `<autocomplete>` to include `@input` and `:search-input` properties.

```
    <v-autocomplete 
        v-model="defendantCode"
        label="Defendant Code"
        :items="defendantCodeOptions"                          
        :loading="defendantCodeIsLoading"
        :filter="customFilter"
        clearable
        multiple
        dense
        @input="searchInput=null"
        :search-input.sync="searchInput">
    </v-autocomplete>
```

Then you'll want to include a data property for `searchInput`:

```
    data() {
        return {
            ...
            searchInput: null,
            ...
        }
    },
```

That's it.

Also, I'm guessing you guessed `:clear-on-select` which doesn't do anything.

Comment: that worked! but I did have to make a little change :search-input.sync. Maybe you could edit your answer?

Comment: Good catch. Didn't notice it in my testing but makes sense it may be needed.

Comment: Thanks -- this was really annoying me!  In case anyone wants to look, [here's a link to the `VAutocomplete` code](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VAutocomplete/VAutocomplete.ts)

Comment: yes, but it is not a solution. It is a work-around for the BUG